# UITableview accessory type disappear while scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have made a tableView in which i need to select multiple options. The options are selected but when i scroll the table view the check mark option get disappear and some other rows displays that check mark.
This is my code in `didselectedrowAtindex` method `table_option` is `UITableView` and `selectedcells` is `NSMutableArray`

```
[table_option deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:indexPath.row];
if ( [selectedCells containsObject:rowNsNum]  )
{
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    else 
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;



    [selectedCells removeObject:rowNsNum];
    sel.text=@"Select";
   // cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
    else 
{
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    else 
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    [selectedCells addObject:rowNsNum];
   sel.text=@"Selected";
   // cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}



[table_option reloadData];
```

pls help soon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to check the cell is already selected or not in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. This issue is happening because tableView re-uses the cells.
Please write the below code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, it'll solve the issue.

```
NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:indexPath.row];
if ( [selectedCells containsObject:rowNsNum]  )
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks alot.. this solve the problem ...thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

In my case just setting `accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` didn't work.

The problem occurs when the `UITableView` reaches its first element and if you try to scroll more, the visible cells go down and their checkmarks gets gone.

```
NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:indexPath.row];

[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];// tricky part is this line

if ( [selectedCells containsObject:rowNsNum]  )
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
 for (int x = 0; x < selectedIds.count; x++) {
     if ([[selectedIds objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:[[source objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"id"]])
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
 }
```