# ios TableViewcell set checkmark but scrolling time checkmark is Auto hide and try to solve it creash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have a tableview cell and this is binding from one array and select to multipal cell and set to checkmark but when i scroll table the checkmark is auto hide 
and then i search on stackoverflow and i find one answier 
the link is 
[UITableview accessory type disappear while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026430/uitableview-accessory-type-disappear-while-scrolling)

i tried this code but app is crash Here is my code, please Help me

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"FirstTableViewCell";

   FirstTableViewCell  *cell = (FirstTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if(tableView ==nurseTypeTable){
        cell.lbl1.text = [arrayNurseType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if(_nurseArray.count != nil){
      //  if (_nurseArray == nil || [_nurseArray count] == 0) {
        NSNumber *rowNsNum = [_nurseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ( [arrayNurseType containsObject:rowNsNum]  )
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString * cellValue=nil;
    if (tableView==nurseTypeTable) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        //Here is for Check
        if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            //here i add  in array
            cellValue=[arrayNurseType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"%@",cellValue);

            [_nurseArray addObject:cellValue];
            NSLog(@"%@",_nurseArray);

        }
        //Here is for uncheck
        else {
            cellValue=[arrayNurseType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [_nurseArray removeObject:cellValue];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            NSLog(@"Remove Array  %@",_nurseArray);
        }
        // [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    }
```

in function **cellForRowAtIndexPath**   **

```
NSNumber *rowNsNum = [_nurseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];** is creash on debug time 
arrayNurseType = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@" Nurse ",@"One",nil]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
     if(tableView ==nurseTypeTable){
        cell.lbl1.text = [arrayNurseType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if(_nurseArray.count != nil){
      //  if (_nurseArray == nil || [_nurseArray count] == 0) {
        if ( [_nurseArray containsObject:indexPath]  )
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: not a problem in array checking if conditon  the problem in next line 
rowNsNum is this code is crash my app

Comment: [_nurseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; its a problem dont use this line in cellforrow method. Because if _nurseArray has 2 object and numberoflines is 5 then it will try to take objects more than 2