# UITableView hides accessory checkmark when scrolled up or down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i tried with multiple answers in stack overflow, but when i scroll table view,accessory checkmark disappear when i scroll up or down.

[This One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13026499/2522603).

My Code---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
PackageTableCell *cell = (PackageTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:packageCell];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[PackageTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:packageCell];
}
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

JobAndPackDetails *objJobAndPackDetails =[self.arrayOfJobList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([objJobAndPackDetails.jobType isEqualToString:@"JPK"])
{
    [cell.imgJPK setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vs_package.png"]];
}
else{
     [cell.imgJPK setImage:nil];
}
 NSIndexPath *indexPathP = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPathP animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];

if ( [self.arrayOfJobList containsObject:rowNsNum]  )
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark ;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}


[cell.lblJobName setText:objJobAndPackDetails.jobName];
[cell.lblJobDescription setText:objJobAndPackDetails.jobDesc];
[cell.lblJobCreated setText:objJobAndPackDetails.jobType];
[cell.lblJobSK setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",objJobAndPackDetails.jobSK]];
[cell.imgVehicle setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
PackageTableCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
NSString *str_JobType = cell.lblJobCreated.text;
NSString *str_JobSK = cell.lblJobSK.text;


if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    if ([str_JobType isEqualToString:@"JOB"])
    {
        [self.array_Job removeLastObject];
        [self.array_JobSK removeLastObject];
        NSLog(@"JOB :%@",self.array_Job);
        NSLog(@"JOB_SK :%@",self.array_JobSK);

    }
    else
    {
        [self.array_Package removeLastObject];
        [self.array_PackageSK removeLastObject];

        NSLog(@"PACKAGE :%@",self.array_Package);
        NSLog(@"Package_SK :%@",self.array_PackageSK);
    }
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    NSLog(@"Selected Job Type Text :%@",str_JobType);


    if ([str_JobType isEqualToString:@"JOB"])
    {
        [self.array_Job addObject:str_JobType];
        [self.array_JobSK addObject:str_JobSK];

        NSLog(@"JOB :%lu",(unsigned long)self.array_Job.count);
        NSLog(@"JOB_SK :%@",self.array_JobSK);



        NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        for (int i = 1; i <= self.array_Job.count; i ++)
        {
            [tmpDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0] forKey:@"AppointmentJobSK"];
            [tmpDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0] forKey:@"AppointmentSK"];
            [tmpDict setObject:str_JobType forKey:@"JobType"];
            [tmpDict setObject:str_JobSK forKey:@"JobTypeSK"];
            [tmpDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",5] forKey:@"UserCreated"];
            [tmpDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2016-04-14 10:00:00"] forKey:@"DateCreated"];

            NSMutableArray *dictAllKeys=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tmpDict allKeys]];
            NSMutableArray *dictAllValues=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tmpDict allValues]];
            Job_keysAndValues=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictAllKeys arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dictAllValues]];
            NSLog(@"Key and Values :%@",Job_keysAndValues);
        }
        Job_dict = tmpDict;
        NSLog(@"Dict :%@",Job_dict);
    }
    else
    {
        [self.array_Package addObject:str_JobType];
        [self.array_PackageSK addObject:str_JobSK];

        NSLog(@"PACKAGE :%@",self.array_Package);
        NSLog(@"Package_SK :%@",self.array_PackageSK);

        NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        for (int i = 1; i <= self.array_Package.count; i ++)
        {
            [tmpDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0] forKey:@"AppointmentJobSK"];
            [tmpDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0] forKey:@"AppointmentSK"];
            [tmpDict setObject:str_JobType forKey:@"JobType"];
            [tmpDict setObject:str_JobSK forKey:@"JobTypeSK"];
            [tmpDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",5] forKey:@"UserCreated"];
            [tmpDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2016-04-14 10:00:00"] forKey:@"DateCreated"];

            NSMutableArray *dictAllKeys=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tmpDict allKeys]];
            NSMutableArray *dictAllValues=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tmpDict allValues]];
            Package_keysAndValues=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictAllKeys arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dictAllValues]];
        }
        Package_dict = tmpDict;
        NSLog(@"Dict :%@",Package_dict);

    }

    NSMutableDictionary *merged = Job_dict.mutableCopy;
    [merged addEntriesFromDictionary: Package_dict];
    NSLog(@"Package Dict:%@",merged);
}

}
```

Comment: As always, **do not** misuse the view (the cell) in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Design your model (the data source array) to mirror the state of the accessory type. Then change the model and reload the view.

Comment: You should not check array as [self.arrayOfJobList containsObject:rowNsNum] as it will return TRUE every time if the object exist in the array instead you should do if ([[self.arrayOfJobList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] isEqualTo: @"Checked" / @"Unchecked"]).

Comment: @vadian i agree with u can u give hint based on my question that how should i redesign model of datasource

Comment: A lot of irrelevant code, use of cell's state for internal logic.

Comment: @Andy could u suggest me where i could made changes

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you are checking in arrayOfJobList for information on wether the cell should have checkmark or not. However, in tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: you did not store any information in arrayOfJobList about it being selected.

Also on a sidenote, you're removing last item item from array_Job, array_JobSK, array_Package and array_PackageSK upon deselection, but you don't check if the deselected item is actually the last one that was put in that array?
For example, if you select cells items A, B and C, deselect A, you would remove C from those arrays?